# Android SoundPool logs info as error

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm developing an Android App using the SoundPool. Every time I play a sound, an error gets logged in LogCat of the type:
E/SoundPool(11873): sampleID=33, leftVolume=0.779528, rightVolume=0.779528, priority=1, loop=0, rate=1.000000

What does this error mean? Is it possible to disable these logs, I guess logging these errors is quite time consuming since I play a lot of sounds.

Thanks

I'm using API 8 and test the App on a Samsung Galaxy S Plus with Android 2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

A took a quick look over the SoundPool class and didn't find anything immediately, but you should definitely look into what type of audio files you are playing. I think you should try maybe uncompressed file types like .wav to see if that alleviates the problem.

Comment: I'm using ogg files, I cannot use wav files, they would be too large. I will try to see if it changes with mp3, but I cannot use mp3 in the application either because mp3s always have a delay (silent part) in the beginning of about 20 ms.

Comment: I tried with mp3 and with wav files, it's all the same, I always get these errors, seems to be "normal" to log infos as errors...

Comment: It's really weird I just tried using SoundPool on API 8 Samsung Galaxy S w/ .ogg and not getting the same error.